# Why does my code-first ASP.NET MVC app suddenly not work just because I opened it from another location?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, code-first

I have a code-first ASP.NET MVC app that ran smoothly and was able to access the data from SQL Server until I copied the project over to another location and opened it from there.

I get the following errors:

> System.Data.DataException
>   HResult=0x80131501
>   Message=An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.
>   Source=
>
> StackTrace:
>
> Inner Exception 1:
>   EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
>
> Inner Exception 2:
>   SqlException: Database 'C:\Users\BICHE\Desktop\FinalCSharpChallenge\FinalCSharpChallenge\App_Data\StudentContextDB.mdf' already exists. Choose a different database name.
>   Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\BICHE\Desktop\MY REPOS3\The-Tech-Academy-C-Coding-Project\FinalCSharpChallenge\FinalCSharpChallenge\App_Data\StudentContextDB.mdf' as database 'StudentContextDB'.

My questions are: why does this happen just because I moved the project from my desktop to another location on my computer?

Can this be solved by making an "if" statement that proceeds to use the `StudentContextDB` if it exists, and creates it if it doesn't? (My instructor suggested this, so I'm thinking I will try this first)

Lastly, if this is the right solution, what would be the syntax for that particular statement?  I've seen instructions for Drop and Create, but not Use or Create.

I appreciate any insight people may have on this issue!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, GMB! By changing the code in this way, to have a relative database location, would it also ensure that other people could run the app if I sent it to them?

Comment: @FreddyMercury : since this seems relevant for your use case, I am deleting my comments and posting this as an answer, please accept it if you considers that it properly responds to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SqlException: Database '...' already exists. Choose a different database name.

It looks like your code is trying to recreate the database... If this is a new deployment, you probably want a new database ; you should modify your code to have a database location which is *relative* to your application home directory.

The other advantage is that, if you give your application to other people, they will have their database created on their computer under the relative path defined by you, so that will play softly as well.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, GMB! This is what I need.

Comment: Hi again, GMB--not sure if you'll see this, but I've been looking up how to modify my code to have a database location that is relative to my app's home directory, and am not seeing a guide that is relevant to this exact context.  It may be much simpler than I'm making it, but is there a chance you can tell me how to go about this change? Even broad explanation will guide me in the right direction. I apologize if this is really obvious!  I'm a bit new to MVC and SQL. Thank you again for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

Short version here is that the db server still has a reference to the old location of the database.  You moved it and tried to fire up the app and point to a new location of the database with the same name.  The db server doesn't know how to handle that.  It would be better to detach the database from the db server then move the files.

Comment: Thank you for your response, John! I'm looking up how to detach the database  right now.  I'm concerned though, because I need to send this app to my instructor and he would also have a problem opening it if those files cannot be moved.  Is there a way to ensure he could run it on his own machine without problems?